# jQuery - variable scope issue "value assigned is never used"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a radio button uncheck when clicked again
and the below code only works for the first uncheck.

`lastChecked = null;` inside the `if` statement gives warning that "value assigned is never used"
and I suspect that this is the cause of issue which I can't figure out.

What can be done to arrange this variable in correct scope?

```
var lastChecked = null;

$j('input[name=radio-group]:radio').click(function(){
    if (lastChecked == this) {
        this.checked = false;
        lastChecked = null;
    }
    lastChecked = this;
});
```

Comment: will always `lastChecked = this; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be more then one radio button ,but you are handling all of the with only single variable `lastChecked`

Try using [**`.data()`**](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method

```
    $('input[name=radio-group]:radio').click(function () {
    $('input[name=radio-group]:radio').not($(this)).data("lastChecked",false);
    if (!$(this).data("lastChecked")) {
        $(this).data("lastChecked", (this.checked = true))
    } else {
        $(this).data("lastChecked", (this.checked = false))
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/bxry1z6w/1/)

Comment: Thank you. Looks very promising. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

you should use else to assigne value `lastChecked = this;`, otherwise `lastChecked` variable have value of clicked radio button always and never get null

```
$j('input[name=radio-group]:radio').click(function(){
    if (lastChecked == this) {
        this.checked = false;
        lastChecked = null;
    }
    else
   {
    lastChecked = this;
    }
});
```

Also instead of assigning radio button to variable, assign radio button value to it. This will help you better to debug your script like putting alert and check which radio selected etc. see below code

```
$j('input[name=radio-group]:radio').click(function(){
  if (lastChecked == this.value) {
     this.checked = false;
     lastChecked = null;
   }
   else
   {
     lastChecked = this.value;
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but this seems to make other radio buttons uncheck/check at the same time.

Comment: other radio button name attribute should be different, otherwise browser consider all of them under same radio button group and will allow you to check only single radio button i.e. whenever you select any radio button under same name then other will get deselected automatically.

Comment: I have no radio group other than this. It does check/uncheck other radio buttons within the same group at the same time.